# Specific error when I try to pip install openbte

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, installation

I'm very new to using Python. If it helps I'm using PyCharm. I'm trying to get a package called openbte (https://pypi.org/project/openbte/) to work on PyCharm, but I keep getting this error.

> OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

and this as the command output

```
Collecting openbte
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b9/b9/bb0d992d29fe888247ad39994518db9472b4f4ae57814b21fa565d18c161/openbte-0.9.24.tar.gz
Collecting numpy (from openbte)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/42/5a/eaf3de1cd47a5a6baca41215fba0528ee277259604a50229190abf0a6dd2/numpy-1.15.4-cp37-none-win32.whl
Collecting scipy (from openbte)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e8/08/6ceee982af40b23566016e29a7a81ed258e739d2d718e03049446c3ccf31/scipy-1.1.0-cp37-none-win32.whl
Collecting shapely (from openbte)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a2/fb/7a7af9ef7a35d16fa23b127abee272cfc483ca89029b73e92e93cdf36e6b/Shapely-1.6.4.post2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\turtl\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\shapely\setup.py", line 80, in <module>
        from shapely._buildcfg import geos_version_string, geos_version, \
      File "C:\Users\turtl\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\shapely\shapely\_buildcfg.py", line 200, in <module>
        lgeos = CDLL("geos_c.dll")
      File "C:\Users\turtl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
        self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

    ----------------------------------------

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\turtl\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\shapely\
```

Currently ripping my hair out trying to get this to work. Does anyone have any idea how to start solving this error?

**EDIT:** I believe it is because of Shapely. I can install numpy and scipy fine, but Shapely gives me the same error with this as the command output:

```
Collecting Shapely
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a2/fb/7a7af9ef7a35d16fa23b127abee272cfc483ca89029b73e92e93cdf36e6b/Shapely-1.6.4.post2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\turtl\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Shapely\setup.py", line 80, in <module>
        from shapely._buildcfg import geos_version_string, geos_version, \
      File "C:\Users\turtl\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Shapely\shapely\_buildcfg.py", line 200, in <module>
        lgeos = CDLL("geos_c.dll")
      File "C:\Users\turtl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
        self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

    ----------------------------------------

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\turtl\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Shapely\
```

Comment: It looks like `shapely` can't be installed via pip on Windows, [according to the page on pypi](https://pypi.org/project/Shapely/). That page has other installation options that you might want to look into, including through Anaconda - though I don't know how to configure pycharm to do those